Why don't I get any reputation by accepting my own answer?
I am currently writing questions and answers on my research topic namelly indistinguishability obfuscation. It would be great if I could get reputation if I accept my own answer as some of the time I am the only person who will be answering. Why don't I get any reputation by accepting my own answer?

See Accepting your own answer with alternative answers to be worth +2 reputation? and Why do we not receive reputation by accepting a self-answer on [meta.se]

@CodesInChaos May be me, but I would have posted the comment as an answer…, as it wraps it up perfectly (especially, the answers in your 2nd link).

Among the reasons provided in the answers to the Q&As linked to by CodesinChaos, it's to avoid things like your most recent post (quote):

I am posting this question along with the answer so that this acts as a wiki for Indistinguishability Obfuscation.

See, we're a Q&A site and not a wiki.
Stackexchange was made created as a place where people can post questions, to get answers from others — a community thing much different from sites like Wikipedia et al.
But the problem spans well beyond that rather minor nitpick.
To clarify, here's a quote of an answer to Accepting your own answer with alternative answers to be worth +2 reputation?

IMHO, self-accepted answers are a feature that should never have been implemented, and definitely don't want to see used more often.
Normally, "acceptance" means one thing: the accepted answer was able to help the asker in some way.
But a "self-accept" checkmark on an answer has no meaning. Presumably, the user answered their own question because they found the solution on their own - but there's no reason to assume they were able to actually communicate that solution in the answer they posted after the fact.
Indeed, I've seen more than a few self-answers that amounted to little more than "the solution described in Bob's answer worked, with some minor tweaks" - indicating that they either should have accepted Bob's answer, or that Bob's answer has one or more critical flaws (the nature of which which shall now remain a mystery to future readers).
To be fair, some users do come back around and post good, detailed answers to their own questions. And that was probably the motivation behind allowing self-accept in the first place. But they don't get any special placement from it, and good answers should get up-voted anyway... so it all just seems rather pointless.

And to quote an answer to Why do we not receive reputation by accepting a self-answer

By allowing people to self award rep in any way you give an incentive to abuse the system. It encourages people to ask questions with the goal of self answering. It biases them to prefer their own answer even if they get another, more suitable one.
And even if they will eventually be dealt with, it does incentivise the posting of garbage questions and answers for the sake of rep. People don't need those questions added to their queues.
By contrast, the potential gain of just allowing people to get more rep is not very useful. Especially when you consider how often people generally accept their own answers right now.

All that should give you a good idea why you don't gain reputation when self-accepting answers.
Hope that helps…
